# Error shown while connecting Flutter App to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I've added all dependencies like:

```yaml
firebase_core: ^2.5.0
firebase_auth: ^4.2.6
```

And also setup Firebase console perfectly after running it was showing error.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: The error that appears , does it just show for this project or all your projects ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: read the first red error]

for solving this go to firebase and open the project you are adding into your app then go to the feature that your adding in your app for example :- (authentication) when you open authentication in firebase on the top you’ll see the rules option click on it and then change your rules.. by default rules don’t allow to read/write but we want to change this to allow..

[image: before]

[image: after]